# Google assistant on Raspberry pi B3 won't start

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I have tried building the Google Assistant on my Raspberry pi model b3 following this walkthrough 
https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/run-sample

Everything went well until I tried starting it with

```
google-assistant-demo
```

and I get the following stacktrace

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/bin/google-assistant-demo", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/assistant/__main__.py", line 66, in main
    with Assistant(credentials) as assistant:
  File "/home/pi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/assistant/library/assistant.py", line 86, in __init__
    self._event_queue = IterableEventQueue()
  File "/home/pi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/assistant/library/event.py", line 172, in __init__
    super(IterableEventQueue, self).__init__(maxsize=32)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

I don't even know where to start and have not tried any solutions. What could be causing the exception?

Comment: You didn't configure the venv properly and now it's trying to run on Python 2 instead of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/run-sample#configure_a_new_python_virtual_environment):
The Google Assistant library currently require [Python > 3.4](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

You can configure a [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) using the following commands:

```
python3 -m venv env
env/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
source env/bin/activate
```

Comment: While this did not exactly solve my problem it pointed me in the right direction. The call to 'google-assistant-demo' did invoke python 2 methods. I went through the setup from beginning to end and in each place where a 'python' command was used I replaced it with 'python3' thanks for your help!